# mac os high sierra ImageMagick 6.9.12-34 need help with multiple file convert

Tags: terminal

I am injecting a jpeg background into the transparent layer of a .png using terminal with ImageMagick 6.9.12-34
I use this and it works for 1 image at a time. I need to use it on every .png in folder

```
Convert background multibackground.jpeg 22213-168.png -gravity center -compose over -composite “output/22213-186.png”
```

(Multibackground.png is the background I’m adding to the transparent layer)

(22213-168.png is the avatar with transparent background)

(“Output” is the folder it is sent to and 22213.168.png is the finished product with background

For removing background I used:

```
convert -transparent “#638596” 22213.png 22213-168.png
```

22213.png was the original and 22213-168.png was to be new output with transparent background

To run every .png file in directory at once I ran:

```
convert -transparent "#8e6fb6" *.png "output/ *.png"
```

Using *.png to target all .png files

I try using this to inject all the backgrounds at once but only get 1 file that is partially done:

```
Convert background multibackground.jpeg *.png -gravity center -compose over -composite “output/ *.png”
```

Answer (score 1):

You're quoting the glob for the input but not the output --  `*.png` vs `"output/ *.png"`. This causes your shell to expand the input but not the output. Try quoting both.
See also:

- https://askubuntu.com/a/1354222/175763
- https://legacy.imagemagick.org/Usage/files/#save_escapes